# how do i convert or display the color base on the color code inside the datagridview cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to display a simple color on the background of the cells int the color column only?

[image]

how do I display the color instead of the color code atleast the background color of the cell itself? btw i'm using the fullrowselect..

my code for loading the database

```
SuspendLayout();
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
        {
            //string cell = dataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT productid,description,color,quantity,unitprice FROM deqor.tblproducts where category=?cat;";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cat", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                try
                {
                    sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    datset = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(datset);
                    bsource = new BindingSource();


                    bsource.DataSource = datset;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
                    DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
                    column.HeaderText = "Code";
                    column.Width = 160;
                    DataGridViewColumn column1 = dataGridView1.Columns[1];
                    column1.HeaderText = "Brand";
                    column1.Width = 220;
                    DataGridViewColumn column2 = dataGridView1.Columns[2];
                    column2.HeaderText = "Color";
                    column2.Width = 100;
                    DataGridViewColumn column3 = dataGridView1.Columns[3];
                    column3.HeaderText = "Quantity";
                    column3.Width = 50;
                    DataGridViewColumn column4 = dataGridView1.Columns[4];
                    column4.HeaderText = "Price";
                    column4.Width = 50;

                    sda.Update(datset);
                    if (dataGridView1.RowCount < 1)
                    {
                        datset.Clear();

                        string row = "NO items found";
                        datset.Rows.Add(row);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
        ResumeLayout();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the color during the `CellFormatting` event, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an explanation

**Example**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if we're formatting the color column
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Color")
    {
        //Make sure there's a value set
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string colorCode = (string)e.Value;
            ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = (Color)cc.ConvertFromString("#" + colorCode);
            //If you don't want the code to show
            e.Value = "";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the reader for this. The code is meant to be used for the DataGridView's CellFormatting event. You can set it up via the designer or in your constructor using `this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting;`

Comment: I've already raised an event in the cell formating in dvg1 and I think I'm missing something and where do i use that this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting += this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting; sorry for being noob

Comment: my column was color instead of Color thats why it not working a while thank you very much

Comment: i'm having minor erorr in your code How do i convert if the values are words like #navy,#red,black yellow or any primary colors?

Comment: There's no way to convert both hex and color names in one method (that I know of). If converting the color fails, using a try-catch try to convert from the name. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link for information on `Color.FromName`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `foreach` for every cell in column[2] and fill it like that:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[count].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```